# Using std::function and std::bind to store callback and handle object deletion.

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function, stdbind

I want to implement a manager that stores callbacks to member functions of polymorphic classes using C++11. The issue is that I am not sure how to handle the case where the object that the member belongs to gets deleted or should be deleted and I want to make the interface as simple as possible.

So I thought of the following: Store a `std::weak_ptr` to the object as well as a `std::function` to the member.

The following seems to work:

```
class MyBase {
public:
    MyBase() {}
    virtual ~MyBase() {}
};
//--------------------------------------------------

class MyClass : public MyBase {
public:
    MyClass() : MyBase() {}
    void myDouble(double val) const { std::cout << "Value is: " << val << std::endl; }
};
//--------------------------------------------------

Class Manager {
public:
    void setFunction(std::weak_ptr<MyBase> base, std::function<void(double)> func) {
        m_function.first  = base;
        m_function.second = func;
    }
private:
    std::pair<std::weak_ptr<MyBase>, std::function<void(double)>> m_function;
};
```

To use this:

```
Manager db;
std::shared_ptr<MyClass> myClass = std::make_shared<MyClass>();
db.setFunction(myClass, std::bind(&MyClass::myDouble, myClass, std::placeholders::_1));
```

Now I want to hide the `std::bind` part from the user, so that he only needs to call:

```
db.setFunction(myClass, &MyClass::myDouble);
```

So I want to get almost the following working in my manager function:

```
void setFunc2(std::weak_ptr<MyBase> base, std::function<void(double)> func) {
    m_function.first  = base;
    m_function.second = std::bind(func, base, std::placeholders::_1);
}
```

But the above gives errors:

```
error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'std::function<void(double)>' and 
'std::_Bind_helper<false, std::function<void(double)>&, std::weak_ptr<MyBase>&, const std::_Placeholder<1>&>::type {aka std::_Bind<std::function<void(double)>(std::weak_ptr<MyBase>, std::_Placeholder<1>)>}')
         m_function.second = std::bind(func, base, std::placeholders::_1);
```

Is there a better way to do this, or perhaps a way to get this working?

Something interesting that I notice. If I use the `std::shared_ptr` the `use_count()` gets incremented with the call to `std::bind` in the original code. Thus I can not manually reset/destroy the object unless I unset the member on my manager. Where is this behaviour documented, I normally use [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)?

I have looked at the following question but can't seem to get it working for my problem: [How can I use polymorphism with std::function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173185/how-can-i-use-polymorphism-with-stdfunction)

Comment: Regarding shared_ptr use count, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind says "The return type of std::bind holds [...] one object per each of args..., [...] constructed from std::forward<Arg_i>(arg_i)." and lower on the same page "The arguments to bind are copied or moved,". Since you passed a shared_ptr lvalue, you got a copy.

Comment: `&MyClass::myDouble` won't convert to `std::function<void(double)>` anyway.

Comment: @T.C I am fully aware of that, thus the reason for the question. I don't care what the signature looks like, I want the call to look like `db.setFunction(myClass, &MyClass::myDouble);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Template `setFunction` so that you can accept pointer-to-member-of-derived, and don't have to write 12 overloads for the combinations of cv/ref qualifiers.

```
template<class D, class D2, class F>
void setFunction(const std::shared_ptr<D> &sp, F D2::* member) {
    // optionally static_assert that D2 is a base of D.
    m_function.first  = sp;
    m_function.second = std::bind(member, sp.get(), std::placeholders::_1);
}
```

Obviously you need to make sure you `lock()` `m_function.first` before calling `m_function.second`.

Alternatively, just use a lambda that captures both the `weak_ptr` and the member function pointer:

```
std::function<void(double)> m_function;

template<class D, class D2, class F>
void setFunction(const std::shared_ptr<D> &sp, F D2::* member) {
    std::weak_ptr<D> wp = sp;
    m_function = [wp, member](double d) {
        if(auto sp = wp.lock()){
             ((*sp).*member)(d);
        }
        else {
             // handle pointer no longer valid case.
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Luckily the compiler does throw an error `cannot convert 'random* const' to 'MyBase*' in assignment`. For interest sake, how would such a `static_assert` look to do the check: `static_assert(std::is_base_of<MyBase, D>::value == true, "Object must be a derived class of \'MyBase\'");`

Comment: Is there a smart way to handle `db.setFunction(myClass, nullptr);`. For the example it does not make sense, but in my actual code it does.

Comment: @TheBadger Define "handle".

Comment: Sorry. So that the function can be called with a `nullptr` or `void` (no method) and then to be able to detect it inside the function. If I just call the function as above I get compiler errors

Comment: @TheBadger `template<class D> void setFunction(const std::shared_ptr<D> &sp, std::nullptr_t) { .... }`

Comment: So I implement an overloaded function specifically for the `nullptr` case(s). It does work well thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I like decoupling my listener/broadcaster from the implementation of the listener.

This means I cannot place requirements on the listener.  It cannot require the listener be allocated in a particular way.

The easiest method I have found is to have the broadcaster return a token whose lifetime determines the lifetime of the connection.

```
using token = std::shared_ptr<void>;

template<class...Args>
struct broadcaster {
  using target = std::function<void(Args...)>;
  using wp_target = std::weak_ptr<target>;
  using sp_target = std::shared_ptr<target>;
  static sp_target wrap_target( target t ) {
    return std::make_shared<target>(std::move(t));
  };

  token start_to_listen( target f ) {
    auto t = wrap_target(std::move(f));
    targets.push_back(t);
    return t;
  }
  void broadcast( Args... args ) {
    targets.erase(
      std::remove_if( targets.begin(), targets.end(),
        [&]( wp_target t )->bool { return t.expired(); }
      ),
      targets.end()
    );
    auto targets_copy = targets; // in case targets is modified by listeners
    for (auto wp : targets_copy) {
      if (auto sp = wp.lock()) {
        (*sp)(args...);
      }
    }
  }
  std::vector<wp_target> targets;
};
```

this forces people who register listeners to keep `std::shared_ptr<void>` around.

We can even make it fancier, where the destruction of the last `shared_ptr<void>` actually removes the listener from the list immediately.  But the above lazy deregistration seems to work reasonably well in my experience, and it is relatively easy to make it multi-thread friendly.  (one serious problem is what happens when a broadcast event removes or adds things to the list of listeners: adapting the above for it to work is nice and easy with the rule that listeners added when broadcasting do not get the broadcast, and listeners removed during broadcasting do not get the broadcast.  Listeners removed *concurrently* during broadcast can get the broadcast in most of my implementations...  That gets expensive to avoid.)

---

We could instead decouple it differently.  The listener could pass a `std::function` and a `std::weak_ptr` separately to the broadcaster, who stores both and only calls the `std::function` if the `std::weak_ptr` is valid.

Comment: In the first line of `start_to_listen()` what is the lifetime and "allocation space" of `std::move(f)`? (Will it be allocated on heap? -- I don't know much about rvalue references atm.)

Comment: @acsor I move construct a shared ptr to the std function, shove it into a vector of weak pointers, then return a shared ptr to void.  The data managed by the shared ptr is on the heap.

Comment: Thanks @Yakk, I actually solved this myself little ago by noting that `std::make_shared()` makes a copy of data and stores it on heap. That was the piece I was missing ;-).

Comment: It seems that `-> bool { return t.lock(); }` should be `-> { return t.expired(); }`.

Answer (score 1):

I like Yakk's approach.  Here's an updated version that fixes a few compile issues (e.g. cannot name function 'register'). It also adds a rm_callback method for clients to easily remove their registration without forcing their registration token to go out of scope or knowing the internals.  I didn't like scanning the list every time an event was broadcast so I added a deleter on the shared pointer which does the cleanup task.  All new bugs introduced or inefficiencies are mine.  The alert reader should be aware of threading issues when modifying the list while broadcasting...

```
using token = std::shared_ptr<void>;
template<class...Args>
struct broadcaster {
    using target = std::function<void(Args...)>;
    using wp_target = std::weak_ptr<target>;
    using sp_target = std::shared_ptr<target>;

    token add_callback(target f) {
        sp_target t(new target(std::move(f)), [&](target*obj) { delete obj; cleanup(); });
        targets.push_back(t);
        return t;
    }

    static void rm_callback(token& t)
    {
        t.reset();
    }

    void cleanup()
    {
        targets.erase(
            std::remove_if(targets.begin(), targets.end(),
                [](wp_target t) { return t.expired(); }
            ),
            targets.end()
        );
    }

    void broadcast(Args... args) {
        for (auto wp : targets) {
            if (auto sp = wp.lock()) {
                (*sp)(args...);
            }
        }
    }

    std::vector<wp_target> targets;
};

// declare event taking a string arg
broadcaster<std::string> myEvent;
```

Comment: Your `add_callback` presumes the broadcaster outlives the listener token by implicitly capturing `this`.  If your lambda outlives the local scope, never use `[&]` as it hides such dependencies.  Second, you probably want to *copy* `targets` in `broadcast`, as if the broadcast list is modified by a listener the `for(:)` loop invariants are going to fail.  Mine also had one of these errors; fixed it in mine.